# Google Map multiple autocomplete

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have been trying to get the json returned by google map. I can do it with individual autocomplete fields, but couldn't do it with multiple autocomplete fields. Have been solving this for the whole afternoon. I can't seems to use getPlaces.

```
function initialize() {

var acInputs = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete");

for (var i = 0; i < acInputs.length; i++) {

    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(acInputs[i]);
    autocomplete.inputId = acInputs[i].id;

    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
      var place = autocomplete.getPlaces();
      console.log(place);
      document.getElementById("placeid"+this.inputId).value = place.place_id;

    });
 }
}
```

Here is the link of jsfiddle,

https://jsfiddle.net/3qbngfm6/8/

Comment: The posted code works is using `getPlaces`, the correct function for autocomplete is `getPlace` and there is a typo in your fiddle (you are using google.maps.event.addListener there, not autocomplete.addListener, that has a different signature). ([working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/3qbngfm6/22/))

Comment: Thanks mate. Wow I spend my whole afternoon debugging it work, should have ask for help earlier.